# How can I egrep this expression

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I have a text file with the following strings, each in a separate line

```
Host: 22.44.55.33 (x.y.z)   Status: Up
```

what I need to extract from lines is the string between the brackets `x.y.z` .

How can I do this using grep in Linux?

Answer (score 4):

```
echo "Host: 22.44.55.33 (x.y.z)   Status: Up" | egrep -o "\([^)]*\)"
(x.y.z)
```

The re `\([^)]*\)` means that you need `(`, then any symbols except `)` and then `)`. The `-o` key of `grep` says that `grep` needs to print only that part of the input text that matches the regular expression.

If you want only that lines that have "Host: Up" inside, you can use assertions:

```
$ cat 1.txt 
(1.2.3.4) Host: Up
(5.6.7.8) Host: Down
(9.1.2.3) Host: Up

$ grep -oP '\([^)]*\)(?=.*Host: Up)' 1.txt
(1.2.3.4)
(9.1.2.3)
```

The main point here is `(?=.*Host: Up)` that says that you want `Host: Up` in the line.

Comment: Guessing that the "Status: Up" part is important, the sed solution by @legoscia would be more useful. But I didn't know about the -o option, so +1.

Comment: Well, even if not explicitly stated in the OP's question, this looks like trying to build a list of the servers that have "Status: Up". When using egrep like this, you'd have to grep two times whereas with the answer given by legoscia, you can have the result in a single step.

Comment: @Axel: With `grep` it is not a problem at all to get the result in one step, but how you can get the result in one step with the answer given by legoscia?

Comment: You don't need `cat`: `grep -oP '\([^)]*\)(?=.*Host: Up)' 1.txt` (http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#cat)

Comment: @Matteo: Thank you for the hint! That is a great feature of `grep` :)

Answer (score 2):

You need `sed`, not `egrep` - `sed` can edit the text, while `egrep` can only choose lines of text and print them unchanged.  Something like this:

```
sed -e 's/^Host:.*(\([^)]*\)).*$/\1/' < inputfile.txt
```